# Can a object be hidden in NSDictionary. Not removing from dictionary just hidden

Tags: ios, key, nsdictionary

I am sorry if this seems as a dumb question. I wana just hidden an object from dictionary so that when NSlogged the hidden key/value pair is not printed but is still present in the dictionary.Then use it later when required.

Is it possible?

Comment: You could create your own `NSDictionary` subclass and override `description`

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't. If you want a private dictionary then create a new one rather than having the key/value pairs in the original dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to disable some keys from being printed using Method swizzling. Solution is in Swift, but it should be similar in Objective-C:

```
extension NSDictionary {

var hiddenKeys : [AnyObject]!{

    get{
        return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &DictionaryAssociationKey) as? [AnyObject]
    }

    set(newValue){
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &DictionaryAssociationKey, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
    }
}


override public class func initialize() {
    struct Static {
        static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
    }


    dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
        let originalSelector = #selector(NSDictionary.description)
        let swizzledSelector = #selector(NSDictionary.modifiedDescription)

        let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector)
        let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledSelector)

        _ = class_addMethod(self, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod))

        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)

    }
}

func modifiedDescription() -> String{
    if let keys = self.hiddenKeys{
        let newDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: self)
        newDictionary.removeObjectsForKeys(keys)

        return newDictionary.description
    }

    return modifiedDescription()
}
}
```

Usage:

```
let dictionary = NSDictionary(objects: ["Hossam", "12345"], forKeys: ["name", "password"])
    dictionary.hiddenKeys = ["password"]
    print(dictionary) // { name = Hossam; }
```

Idea is I create an extension to `NSDictionary` so you don't need to subclass and change the whole app. Then added a property called `hiddenKeys` that you can add inside it the keys to hidden that will not be shown in `description`.

Answer (score 0):

Giving you an example of dictionary

```
  NSDictionary *prices = @{
                             @"Mercedes-Benz SLK250" : [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"42900.00"],
                             @"Mercedes-Benz E350" : [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"51000.00"],
                             @"BMW M3 Coupe" : [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"62000.00"],
                             @"BMW X6" : [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"55015.00"]
                             };
```

Just listing the keys with price less then 55000

```
NSDecimalNumber *maximumPrice = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"55000.00"];
    NSSet *under55k = [prices keysOfEntriesPassingTest:
                       ^BOOL(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
                           if ([obj compare:maximumPrice] == NSOrderedAscending) {//Use your if condition to show hide object
                               return YES;
                           } else {
                               return NO;
                           }
                       }];
    NSLog(@"%@", under55k);
```

Answer:

```
{(
    "Mercedes-Benz E350",
    "Mercedes-Benz SLK250"
)}
```

You can use **keysOfEntriesPassingTest** to specify your filter options and replace the if condition of comparison with our condition to show or hide object.